# Check valid schedule area on event move

Tags: java, primefaces

I have a schedule with events. Each one has an authorised range of dates, and I would like to prevent an event from being moved outside its range. For example, an event might be able to move in the range 01-01-2014 to 01-30-2014. I can find those parameters in my controller.

planning.xhtml:

```xml
<h:form id="agenda">
    <p:panel id="panelSchedule" header="Agenda" styleClass="panelSchedule">
        <p:growl id="messages"/>
        <h:panelGrid columnClasses="scheduleColumn">

            <!-- Binding schedule and event -->
            <p:schedule id="schedule" 
                        locale="fr" 
                        value="#{planningController.eventModel}" 
                        widgetVar="myschedule" 
                        resizable="false" 
                        timeZone="CET" 
                        timeFormat="H:mm" 
                        columnFormat="week:'ddd dd/MM', day:'dddd dd/MM'" axisFormat="H:mm">
                <p:ajax event="dateSelect" 
                        listener="#{planningController.onDateSelect}" 
                        update="eventDetails" 
                        oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" 
                        disabled="#{planningController.disabledCalendar}"/>
                <p:ajax event="eventSelect" 
                        listener="#{planningController.onEventSelect}" 
                        update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />
                <p:ajax event="eventMove" 
                        listener="#{planningController.onEventMove}" 
                        update="messages" />
            </p:schedule>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

planningController.java:

```
public void onEventMove(ScheduleEntryMoveEvent event) {
    if (event move on wrong range) {
        // don't move the event
    } else {
        // it's ok, you can move event
    }
}
```

I don’t need detailed code, just a good place to start. I’ve tried searching, but I don’t know the right terms to use.

Answer (score 0):

From the PrimeFaces' API concerning [ScheduleEntryMoveEvent](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.1/org/primefaces/event/ScheduleEntryMoveEvent.html), you can use the `getDayDelta()` method as well as the `getScheduleEvent().getStartDate()` and `getScheduleEvent().getEndDate()` to make your calculations that verifies if the modified event's date is within its allowed range.

Comment: Thank you for your response, there is a strange troubleshoot when i getStartDate from getScheduleEvent, it don't give me the correct original date but i will be took a different way to get it. Now it work fine but i loose roll back effect from the schedule.